# Dissolve a Geometric Network in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, dissolve, geometric-network

I have a geometric network of water mains in ArcGIS. It it composed of a line feature class. I would like to dissolve it based on whether line segments share common endpoints only.
[image]

So basically Everything in the picture should dissolve together except for the Eastern North-South running line because it crosses over the other lines and does not share any nodes. However, when I run a standard Dissolve, all of the features run together.

Comment: can you select the connecting nodes before running the dissolve?

Comment: The nodes are just part of the feature geometry